# WiX Repeat Dynamic Configurable Build?

Tags: dynamic, msbuild, batch-file, wix, wix3

I have a .wixproj in VS 2010 that makes a MSI just the way I need it (using heat for harvesting in the pre build event). Now I need to distribute 3 versions of the same thing, that only need to differ in app.config settings, output MSI name, and some dialog stuff defined in some secondary .wxs files.

I was thinking about creating a console app that would take parameters and modify the .wixproj and .wxs and app.config files and then kick off MSBuild, but that seems like a lot of work.

What would be a better way to use WiX as a build factory so I can have it generate many customized MSI installers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WiX Preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) is your friend here. Using its values and conditional statements will help you to make "universal" sources, which will output various packages based on what you pass in.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled across them around the time you posted your answer. i am still having a problem getting them to work when I do msbuild from the command line vs building in the Visual Studio GUI. I'll mod you up as accepter answer as soon as I get myself straightened out with this (and don't need to edit my question). Thanks.